# Procedure can not be executed

Tags: mariadb

I can run one procedure in one database:

```
$ mysql --user=license --password=test123 --host=mariadb.devlocal --database=license -s '--execute=CALL config_sp_License_Update("missing","29b7ec4250df4fb30ce8634c98ae412a328652bb463749eec7a11b033b1e4eef","0","0","2019-06-19 09:04:26","2019-06-19 09:04:26", "0");'
status
missing
```

But not in the test database:

```
$ mysql --user=license --password=test123 --host=mariadb.devlocal --database=test_license -s '--execute=CALL config_sp_License_Update("missing","29b7ec4250df4fb30ce8634c98ae412a328652bb463749eec7a11b033b1e4eef","0","0","2019-06-19 09:04:26","2019-06-19 09:04:26", "0");'
ERROR 1370 (42000) at line 1: execute command denied to user 'license'@'%' for routine 'test_license.config_sp_License_Update'
```

The grants are correct:

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4653
Server version: 10.4.2-MariaDB-1:10.4.2+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'license'@'%';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for license@%                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'license'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*676243218923905CF94CB52A3C9D3EB30CE8E20D' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `license`.* TO 'license'@'%'                                                   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_license`.* TO 'license'@'%'                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

What is going on? What is special about the `test_license` database? Both `test_license` and `license` databases are initialized wit the same SQL commands

Comment: Does 'config_sp_License_Update' exist in the 'test_license' database?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE config_sp_License_Update \G`; I suspect the answer lies there.